# xpath get first element based on condition

Tags: xpath, conditional-statements

I need my xpath expression to select only the first child element of an xml file based on condition. Say the first having field1=B.
I use this expression but it return that with field1=A.

```
<root>
<entry>
    <field1>A</field1>
    <field2>10</field2>
</entry>
<entry>
    <field1>B</field1>
    <field2>20</field2>
</entry>
```

```
/root/entry[//field1='B' or 'C'][1]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
/root/entry[.//field1='B' or .//field1='C'][1]
```

Note that `entry[//field1='B'][1]` means *return first `entry` node if `field1` node with value `'B'` exists (anywhere in XML)* while `entry[.//field1='B'][1]` means *return first `entry` node if it has a descendant `field1` node with value `'B'`*

Also you can simplify expression as

```
/root/entry[field1='B' or field1='C'][1]
```

if `field1` always appears as direct child of `entry`